# Want to declare an array of vectors

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

Due to some legacy code, I need to declare an array of vectors. I have tried:

```
vector< foo> a[numvecs];
```

then  allocating the vector:

```
a[i]=vector<foo>(foosize);
```

but I can't seem to properly access or write to the inner vectors

```
afile.read((char *)&a[i][0],foosize*sizeof(foo))
```

causes a segfault

I'd declare a vector of vectors, but the outter vector is a fixed size and is very small (usually 1 to 3) and also due to the way the legecy code is written. Plus when I do that and try print anything in the vector I get compiler errors about type mismatches, any clues?

Comment: What about`vector<vector< foo>> a; a.resize(numvecs,vector<foo>(foosize));`?

Comment: `vector<foo> a[numvecs];` is not valid C++ unless `numvecs` is a constant known at compile time; if the code compiles it's because of a compiler extension. Anyway, assuming `foo` is a trivially copyable type, the code you've shown should work.

Comment: Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: note that `vector<foo> a[numvecs];` allocates all of the vectors; the line `a[i] = vector<foo>(foosize);` updates `a[i]` by copying the size and contents of a temporary vector of size `foosize`.  (Which works but is less idiomatic than using `resize`).

Comment: numvecs is psuedocode for an actual number, just like foo is not an actual type the the compiler knows at compile time

Comment: maybe my vector thinking is wrong? I would think that the array would contain what in reality is a bunch of pointers to the location of the vector in memory (since vectors are implemented as linked lists). Since the outer container is an array, it would be in memory sequentially, while the actual vectors could be allocated anywhere. Is my thinking wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `numvecs` is a compile-time constant (or a compiler extension), you can at least change this line:

```
a[i]=vector<foo>(foosize);
```

To this simplified line:

```
a[i].resize(foosize);
```

What you showed to access the `vector` should work fine, provided it has been allocated properly. I would suggest using parenthesis to help the compiler know what you want it to do, though:

```
afile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&(a[i])[0]), foosize*sizeof(foo));
```

Or even use a reference to make it easier to read:

```
vector<foo> &vec = a[i];
afile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&vec[0]), foosize*sizeof(foo));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
vector <vector <foo> > a;

a.resize(<size>);
for(int =0; i < a.size(); i++) {
    a[i].resize(<size>);
}
```

I think this should work